# How to boot to Ubuntu ISO image on drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, startup, iso

I can't boot to the Ubuntu 14.10 ISO I have on my drive (running Ubuntu 14.04 as my main OS btw). I added these lines to the bottom of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry 'ubuntu-iso' {
    set isofile="/boot/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

The Ubuntu ISO is at `/boot/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso`, and I've verified its checksum. `/dev/sda1` is mounted at `/boot`, which is why I've done `(hd0,1)$isofile` above.

Then I run `sudo update-grub`. The new menu entries show up in the grub menu screen, but when I select it and try to boot it just boots to my existing OS instead of the ISO.

Comment: I followed the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot to find the steps I tried above.

Comment: Just an idea. `menuentry "ubuntu-iso" {`

Comment: Is `vmlinuz.efi` correct?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify where your `/boot` is mounted. Is it a separate partition? Is it on `/dev/sda1`? ALso, please post the generated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file or at least the relevant menu entry.

Comment: Grub is before anything is mounted by operating system. So is /boot a mount point or an existing folder in sda1. If a folder it should work. If a mount point then you need to remove the /boot and just use path you see from an external drive without /media/$USER portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but if /dev/sda1 is already mounted at /boot, wouldnt you get a redundant /boot in your path when you're also specifying it in the $isofile variable? I think GRUB is looking for the image in /boot/boot/, so maybe try changing to:

set isofile="ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso"